# javascript function crashes my browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I coded a simple program which take 2 textareas and combine every single line of one textarea with all the lines in the second textarea and my browser crushes after 6000 lines.
The resul of my check needs to get to 100,000 lines.

This is the javascript code:

```
function go() {
    var lines1 = $('#text1').val().split(/\n/);
    var lines2 = $('#text2').val().split(/\n/);
    var textarea1 = [];
    var textarea2 = [];
    var textarea3 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lines1.length; i++) {
        if (/\S/.test(lines1[i])) {
            textarea1.push($.trim(lines1[i]));
        }
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < lines2.length; j++) {
        if (/\S/.test(lines2[j])) {
            textarea2.push($.trim(lines2[j]));
        }
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < lines1.length; k++) {
        for (var q = 0; q < lines2.length; q++) {
            textarea3.push($.trim(lines1[k] + ' ' + lines2[q]));
            var msg = textarea3.join("\n");
            document.getElementById('text3').value = msg;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<textarea name="textarea" id="text1"></textarea>
<textarea name="textarea" id="text2"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="GO!" onclick="go()">
<br />
<textarea name="textarea" id="text3"></textarea>
```

Comment: this prob. isn't the cause for crash, but I recommend moving var msg = textarea3.join("\n"); document.getElementById('text3').value = msg; out of the loop and only traversing & updating the DOM one time once you have built var msg

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this code

```
    for (var k=0; k < lines1.length ; k++) {
        for (var q=0; q < lines2.length ; q++) {
            textarea3.push($.trim(lines1[k] + ' ' + lines2[q]));
            var msg = textarea3.join("\n");
            document.getElementById('text3').value = msg;
        }
    }
```

If there are 1K lines in textarea1 and 1K in testarea2 then you will modify the DOM (by changing the value of textarea3) 1M times which is insane. So instead of updating the DOM every time try to do it outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide maxlength attribute in textarea  and then check I think it will work.

and in your for loops *first store all the content in a variable and then outside for loop write it into textarea rather than each time assigning the DOM value inside for loop.*